# PendingIntent not recreating activity (with Extras) when it is already on history stack top

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to start an Activity **A** from a Notification Button (using PendingIntent). When I tap on this Notification Button and **A** is on top of history stack, it just not behave correctly:

**What it should do:**

- Activity **A** must duplicated on historystack, this way:

  1. When activity **A** **is** on top of history stack

     Before:

     [ A, ... old activities ... ]

     After:

     [ A, A, ... old activities ... ]
  2. When activity **A** **is not** on top of history stack (default behavior)

     Before:

     [ B, ... old activities ... ]

     After:

     [ A, B, ... old activities ... ]

**What happens:**

1. `onCreate` is called, but `getIntent().getExtras()` is `null`.
2. Activity **A** is replaced and not recreated (I want a duplicate).

I've tried a lot of things: `Intent.FLAG*` and `PendingIntent.FLAG*` also, but unsuccessfully.

**Edit 1:**
I tried these constants:

- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`
- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` (but I don't want to clear top)

Code (part):

```
Intent intentCancel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChallengeProposalActivity.class);
//intent.setAction(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra(ChallengeProposal.NAME, proposal);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentCancel, 0);
```

Code (full): http://pastebin.com/vNuEkBvi

---

What should I do?

**Related questions:**

[PendingIntent not working when adding extras in intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766035/pendingintent-not-working-when-adding-extras-in-intent)

[Duplicate MainActivity When Enter From Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606809/duplicate-mainactivity-when-enter-from-notification)

Comment: what Intent.FLAG_* did you try? and how? what is android:launchMode in the Manifest?

Comment: Default value: `standard`. I've read that it is just an alternative to programmatically way. Is it true?

Comment: first of all you should probably use unique `requestCode`s when calling `PendingIntent.getActivity`

Comment: But there's no other `PendingIntent`, this is the first. I already tried it, unsuccessfully.

Comment: so you are saying that you call `putExtra` but still `getExtras` is null? it is impossible...

Comment: Impossible describes it very well... I don't know what's going wrong!

Comment: post your complete code then

Comment: @pskink http://pastebin.com/vNuEkBvi

Comment: Please help me, I don't know what to do.

Comment: try this service http://codeshare.io/Z1h3V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `intentCancel` object, but tried to put extra in `intent` object:

```
Intent intentCancel = new Intent...
intent.putExtra...
```